# Python Print common values into column

Tags: python

I have a csv file, with 2 columns, and about 1000 rows.
Each cell contains from 1 up to 100 values.

I have the two columns separated by : and the values by 'value', 'value'.
Here is a part of my file:

```
'P08588 ':'P08172', 'P11229', 'P20309 '
'P15121 ':'P10145', 'P15121', 'P23219', 'P35354', 'P41222', 'P43116'
'P08588 ':'P23219', 'Q8TCC7 '
```

Here is the code what I have.

```
array1 =('P15121 ')
array2 = ('P10145', 'P15121', 'P23219', 'P35354', 'P41222', 'P43116')
f = set(array1) & set(array2)
print f
```

From this I get an output: P15121

The code what I am showing is working only if I put manually the values of the arrays (so copy & paste from the original file)

I'd like to write a code,, which makes:

open the my csv file,

then, read the first row,

put the the 2 columns into variables,

Check if the the columns have common value

print result into a 3rd coulmn

then go to the next line, and do the same.

Thank you

Comment: What is your question? You give some code, but you don't say what you need from us. Do you get the wrong output? Do you get an error? If it works, you should post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @Viki Your edit doesn't address given your input - what you expect the output to be? The code you've given isn't related to the example given. It's unclear what output you're after?

Comment: I believe you need to learn how to parse a CSV file. Then you'll be able to piece it together with the code you wrote.

Comment: Read this http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Sorry, my previous explanation was quite blurry, I hope my explanation is better this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are trying to do something along the lines of:

```
infile = open(YourFilename)
for line in infile.read():
    (A, B) = line.split(':')
    As = [eval(a).strip() for a in A.split(',')]
    Bs = [eval(b).strip() for b in B.split(',')]
    Com = [A for A in As if A in Bs]
    print As, ':', Bs, '::', Com
```

EDIT:  Corrected the above.

```
>>> infile = open("temp.txt")
>>> for line in infile:
...     if len(line) > 2:
...         (A, B) = line.split(':')
...         As = [eval(a).strip() for a in A.split(',')]
...         Bs = [eval(b).strip() for b in B.split(',')]
...         Com = [A for A in As if A in Bs]
...         print As, ':', Bs, '::', Com
... 
['P08588'] : ['P08172', 'P11229', 'P20309'] :: []
['P15121'] : ['P10145', 'P15121', 'P23219', 'P35354', 'P41222', 'P43116'] :: ['P15121']
['P08588'] : ['P23219', 'Q8TCC7'] :: []
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I would like to do. I tried your code, but I get  the following code:  File "com1.py", line 5, in <module>
    (A, B) = line.split(':')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: You must have a line with nothing or with no : on it.

Comment: I tried only with the example what I given in the question, and I get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry Viki,  2 mistakes above 1) it should be for line in infile: and it needs a check for len(line) > 2: on the next line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now it works perfectly.  Wish you a good day!